# Auto mount iscsi device on system start (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, mount, fstab, iscsi

I want to auto-mount /dev/sda1 (iscsi device) to /iscsi2 on system start so I added the following line to /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=d159d371-379f-4730-a832-0fad31fd3ff6 /iscsi2              ext4       auto,acl,user_xattr,nofail,_netdev 0 2
```

After a system reboot, /iscsi2 is empty. I can't even mount manually:

```
# mount /dev/sda1 /iscsi2
mount: /dev/sda1 is already mounted or /iscsi2 busy
```

However, after waiting some time (2-3 minutes) it works.

What can be done?

I use Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

Thank you!

Comment: Try adding `x-systemd.automount` to the options, if you using systemd, to automount when the directory is accessed.